# The background resets every time the system restarts

Tags: debian, xfce, wallpaper

Every time I change my wallpaper on my dual screens, and I log off, the wallpapers revert to their original state when I log in. Is there a reason why this happens, or is it just what goes on in the world of Linux?

I use Debian Wheezy, and Xfce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go into the desktop manager and play with the settings, I believe you have to go into the settings manager, choose the desktop settings, change single image to image list, choose which wallpaper then repeat for the second monitor.

Answer (score 0):

-Make sure the image is present in a location that is auto mounted to root.

-Check the wallpaper and display settings are not set to changing the wallpaper automatically.

-Add the image into the wallpapers list in settings